# Bottender - Enabling persistent_menu and get_started button on facebook

Tags: node.js, facebook, bots, bottender

I am using NodeJS & [Bottender](https://github.com/Yoctol/bottender) to run my facebook messenger webhook.

So I want to have a `get started button` and a `persistent menu`. I checked & patterned my config on the examples provided on the repo like [this one](https://github.com/Yoctol/bottender/blob/master/examples/messenger-chat-extensions/bottender.config.js) but I can't get it to be present on messenger yet.

here's my config.js

```
require('dotenv').config();

const {
  FB_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  FB_VERIFY_TOKEN,
  APP_ID,
  APP_SECRET,
} = process.env;

const { bots } = require('./global-session');

const profile = {
  get_started: {
    payload: '/start',
  },
  persistent_menu: [
    {
      locale: 'default',
      composer_input_disabled: false,
      call_to_actions: [
        {
          type: 'postback',
          title: 'Menu',
          payload: '/menu',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
/* istanbul ignore next */
module.exports = {
  messenger: {
    bot: {
      accessToken: FB_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      appId: APP_ID,
      appSecret: APP_SECRET,
      mapPageToAccessToken: bots.getTokenByPageById,
      profile,
    },
    server: {
      verifyToken: FB_VERIFY_TOKEN,
      path: '/messenger',
      profile,
    },
  },
};
```

and here's how I use it

```
const { MessengerBot } = require('bottender');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { registerRoutes } = require('bottender/express');
const handler = require('./handlers');
const logger = require('./utils/logger');

const { APP_PORT, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const server = express();

/* istanbul ignore next */
const verify = (req, res, buf) => {
  req.rawBody = buf.toString();
};

server.use(bodyParser.json({ verify }));
server.use(require('morgan')('short', { stream: logger.logStream }));

const { messenger } = require('./config');

const bots = {
  messenger: new MessengerBot(messenger.bot).onEvent(handler.messenger.execute),
  // Define other platform bots here!
};

const initialize = async () => {
  try {
    registerRoutes(server, bots.messenger, messenger.server);
    // Start server
    server.listen(APP_PORT, () => logger.info(`ENV[${NODE_ENV}] - server is listening on port ${APP_PORT}...`));
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error('unable to start server!');
    logger.error(e);
    throw Error();
  }
};

/* istanbul ignore next */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  initialize();
}

module.exports = initialize;
```

Background on my facebook app
- It is already **published to public** and **approved**(at least for `pages_messaging`)

Anything I missed to do? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We leave messenger profile control to developers, because we can't assume when developers want to set, update or delete bots' messenger profile.

For example, you can have a script like this:

```
const { MessengerClient } = require('messaging-api-messenger'); 

const config = require('./bottender.config');

const client = MessengerClient.connect();

const tokens = [ /* */ ]; // get tokens from somewhere

for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
  const token = tokens[i];
  client.setMessengerProfile(config.messenger.profile, {
    access_token: token, // important! pass token to client api
  });
}
```

Or you can call `setMessengerProfile` when you register your token to your database:

```
async function registerPage(page, token) {
  // ....put page and token to database
  await client.setMessengerProfile(config.messenger.profile, {
    access_token: token, // important! pass token to client api
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback! so might be good to remove the profile section on the examples if it doesn't work?

Comment: The profile section is good for one page token, and `bottender messenger profile set` cli can be used to set the profile. But in multiple page tokens case, we can't assume where developers store their page tokens (usually in database), so bottedner cli can't find tokens directly.